# Padronização para uso do MySQLi

Tags: php, mysqli, design-pattern

Estou pesquisando sobre o uso do MySQLi e tenho visto muitos artigos, mas cada um sempre tem algumas particularidades sobre o padrão de desenvolvimento, minha pergunta alguém já definiu um padrão? Por exemplo algo que possa ser seguido com as melhores práticas?

Por exemplo um código de inserção desse artigo aqui:
[PHP MySqli Basic usage (select, insert & update)](http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/03/basic-php-mysqli-usage)

```
real_escape_string('P1234').'"';
$product_name = '"'.$mysqli->real_escape_string('42 inch TV').'"';
$product_price = '"'.$mysqli->real_escape_string('600').'"';

//MySqli Insert Query
$insert_row = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO products (product_code, product_name, price) VALUES($product_code, $product_name, $product_price)");

if($insert_row){
    print 'Success! ID of last inserted record is : ' .$mysqli->insert_id .'
'; 
}else{
    die('Error : ('. $mysqli->errno .') '. $mysqli->error);
}

?>
```

E nesse outro artigo:
[How to Use PHP Improved MySQLi extension](http://www.pontikis.net/blog/how-to-use-php-improved-mysqli-extension-and-why-you-should)

```
$v1="'" . $conn->real_escape_string('col1_value') . "'";

$sql="INSERT INTO tbl (col1_varchar, col2_number) VALUES ($v1,10)";

if($conn->query($sql) === false) {
  trigger_error('Wrong SQL: ' . $sql . ' Error: ' . $conn->error, E_USER_ERROR);
} else {
  $last_inserted_id = $conn->insert_id;
  $affected_rows = $conn->affected_rows;
}
```

Comment: Ferinha, sou mais adépto ao PDO ao Mysqli e seguir os padrões PSR..
Outra coisa, no que tange design partern, nas minhas ultimas aplicações desenvolvidas, eu julguei necessário usar Active Record, tem muita coisa no google sobre isso

Comment: veja esse video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OGzK1uFBJd0
acho que pode lhe ajudar...

Comment: Padrão em que sentido e do que?

Comment: Olá @rray, obrigado por ter perguntado, como seguir um padrão para o CRUD, tenho lido muitos artigos e sempre tem muita coisa diferente.

Comment: Poste exemplos dessa diferença nos artigos

Comment: Sua pergunta está bem incompleta. Informe que padrão você está dizendo e qual finalidad do uso

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Atualmente as bibliotecas de PHP mais utilizadas e seguras são [PDO](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.pdo.php) e [MySQLI](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.mysqli.php)

O **PDO** tem a vantagem de ser adaptativo a diversos banco de dados sem a necessidade de alterar todo o seu código.

Já o **MySQLI** é excelente para projetos que usam apenas MySQL como banco de dados e não visam utilização de outros.

Em qualquer caso **ambos** são seguros e dão conta do recado de projetos pequenos quanto grandes.

Sobre o padrão, não existe algo universal. Vai das suas `necessidades` e seu `gosto`